# OperationalError in django when adding a new record

Tags: python, django

I have created a mysql database with Cpanel . And I have some settings for database in the settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {  
'default': {  
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
    'NAME': '*****_db',  
    'USER': '******',  
    'PASSWORD': '********',  
    'HOST': 'localhost',  
    'PORT': '3306',  
    'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB,character_set_connection=utf8,collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci'
    }
}
```

}

but the problem is when I try to add a new record in django-admin with some arabic chars , I get this error :

```
OperationalError at /admin/courses/arguments/add/
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD8\\xB3\\xDA\\xAF' for column `asiatrad_db`.`courses_arguments`.`name` at row 1")
```

What is the problem ? Do I need to create a new database with charset on utf-8 ?

Comment: Looks like the collation of the db is set differently.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “utf8” encoding only supports three bytes per character. The real UTF-8 encoding, which everybody uses, needs up to four bytes per character. See [this article](https://adamhooper.medium.com/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434).

So use “utf8mb4” charset instead of “utf8”.

The `settings.py` should look as follows:

```
DATABASES = {  
'default': {  
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
    'NAME': '*****_db',  
    'USER': '******',  
    'PASSWORD': '********',  
    'HOST': 'localhost',  
    'PORT': '3306',  
    'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB','charset': 'utf8mb4'}
}
```